# Parsing from CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

I'm trying to get rows from a CSV file without headers.

```
require "csv"

filepath = "data/beatles.csv"
csv_options = { col_sep: ',', quote_char: '"', headers: :first_row }

CSV.foreach(filepath, csv_options) do |row|
   puts row[0]
end
```

And I always got this error:

> `initialize': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)

Comment: If the CSV file is without headers, why are you specifying `headers: :first row`?

Comment: @pjs different interpretation: the OP wants the CSV rows without the header row. (which might make more sense regarding the code)

Answer (score 2):

[CSV::foreach](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/csv#method-c-foreach) expects optional named arguments after the `path_or_io` argument. You're trying to pass it a hash object. You need to ask ruby to expand the hash into a list of the named arguments, which is done with a double-splat:

```ruby
csv_options = { col_sep: ',', quote_char: '"', headers: :first_row }

CSV.foreach(filepath, **csv_options) do |row|
  # whatever
end
```

Correct the `csv_options` as appropriate to match what you actually need to deal with, e.g., don't specify `headers:` if there are none as stated in your question.